# How to remove decimals from file (round them)?

Tags: c#, regex, rounding

I have to open file, find all decimals, remove decimal part, round them and replace in the text. Result text should be print in the Console.
I tried to do it, but the only thing I made was to remove the decimal part. Please tell me how to round them and replace in the result text. Here is my code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter path to first file:");
        String path1 = Console.ReadLine();
        
                    
        string text = File.ReadAllText(path1);
        string pattern = @"(\d+)\.\d+";
        if(File.Exists(path1) ){
            
            foreach(string phrase in Regex.Split(text, pattern)){
                Console.Write(phrase);
            }
            
        Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
        Console.ReadKey(true);      
        }
```

Comment: Can you provide text sample that you use?

Comment: If you remove the fractional part before rounding, there is no fraction to tell you how to round it. After rounding, there is no fractional part.

Comment: Aaaa 50.05 bbbb 82.52 cccc 6.8888

Comment: How I can round before removing it?

Comment: How big are the files, is this a csv by any chance?, are you trying to reduce allocations or reduce allocations on the LOH? does this need to be streamed? Are there any performance constraints? Obviously running a regex on a 1gig file in a hot production system is going to draw the ire of your senior developers, and earn you an award for all the wrong reasons.

Comment: Did any of the answers help you?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `@"\d+([\.\,]\d+)"` pattern to capture each number with any amount of decimals. Then use `Regex.Replace` with *MatchEvaluator*, where parse captured value as `double` then "cut" decimals by simple `ToString("F0")` (check about [Fixed-point format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#FFormatString)).

Example below include decimals with comma `,` or `.` fraction separators with help of `double.TryParse` overload, where we can specify `NumberStyles.Any` and `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` (from `System.Globalization` namespace) and simple replacement of comma `,` to dot `.`. Also works with negative numbers (e.g. -0.98765 in example):

```
var input = "I have 11.23$ and can spend 20,01 of it. "+
            "Melons cost 01.25$ per -0.98765 kg, "+
            "but my mom ordered me to buy 1234.56789 kg. "+
            "Please do something with that decimals.";
var result = Regex.Replace(input, @"\d+([\.\,]\d+)", (match) =>
    double.TryParse(match.Value.Replace(",", "."), NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out double value)
    ? value.ToString("F0")
    : match.Value);

// Result: 
// I have 11$ and can spend 20 of it.
// Melons cost 1$ per -1 kg,
// but my mom ordered me to buy 1235 kg.
// Please do something with that decimals.
```

On `"Aaaa 50.05 bbbb 82.52 cccc 6.8888"` would work too with result of `"Aaaa 50 bbbb 83 cccc 7"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Math.Round`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round) on all matches that you can transform using [`Regex.Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace) and a match evaluator as the replacement:

```cs
var text = "Aaaa 50.05 bbbb 82.52 cccc 6.8888";
var pattern = @"\d+\.\d+";
var result = Regex.Replace(text, pattern, x => $"{Math.Round(Double.Parse(x.Value))}");
Console.WriteLine(result); // => Aaaa 50 bbbb 83 cccc 7
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/CWlQ0k).

The `\d+\.\d+` regex is simple, it matches one or more digits, `.` and one or more digits. `Double.Parse(x.Value)` converts the found value to a *Double*, and then `Math.Round` rounds the number.